# RES memory more than initial and maximum memory for java

Tags: centos, memory, java

We have a java application running on Centos 6.4 what we notice is that the RES is around 370m which is more then the allocated max that is 256m. Does this signify that we the application is leaking?

Comment: There is more to memory that just the heap allocated to JVM. Memory can also be shared between processes.

Comment: So how to detect is this a real case of memory leak? Any indication? What is the more to the memory mind to explain it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java command-line parameters like Xmx sets the maximum RAM for the application heap. There are other memory regions, [like the stack and perm space](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2012/cmsc131-040x/Notes/Slides14-MemoryModel.pdf).